# Get a list of searchable content types in Plone 4

Tags: search, plone, catalog

I am using Products.AdvancedQuery to build a replacement LiveSearch mechanism for my site. So far everything works perfectly, but the standard query performs a search on all available content-types, including the ones marked as non-searchable in the @@search-controlpanel.

I'd like AdvancedQuery to filter out the non-searchable ones dynamically, according to what is specified in @@search-controlpanel. How can I do this?

If AQ cannot do it, I can filter the results right after querying the catalog. I'd need a list of content-type names (or interfaces) that are marked as searchable. How can I obtain such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can obtain a tuple or list of the types that the control panel blacklists programmatically, this might be as simple as (imports elided):

```
>>> query = myquery & AdvancedQuery.Not(AdvancedQuery.In(MY_TYPE_BLACKLIST_HERE)) 
>>> result = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog').evalAdvancedQuery(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. You helped me understand what to do to make it work. I'm adding a reply describing my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to sdupton's suggestion I found a way to make it work.

This is the solution (obvious imports omitted):

```
from Products.AdvancedQuery import (Eq, Not, In, 
                                    RankByQueries_Sum, MatchGlob)

from my.product.interfaces import IQuery


class CatalogQuery(object):

    implements(IQuery)

    ...

    def _search(self, q, limit):
        """Perform the Catalog search on the 'SearchableText' index
        using phrase 'q', and filter any content types 
        blacklisted as 'unsearchable' in the '@@search-controlpanel'.
        """

        # ask the portal_properties tool for a list of names of
        # unsearchable content types
        ptool = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_properties')
        types_not_searched = ptool.site_properties.types_not_searched

        # define the search ranking strategy
        rs = RankByQueries_Sum(
                (Eq('Title', q), 16),
                (Eq('Description', q), 8)
             )

        # tune the normalizer
        norm = 1 + rs.getQueryValueSum()

        # prepare the search glob
        glob = "".join((q, "*"))

        # build the query statement, filter using unsearchable list
        query = MatchGlob('SearchableText', glob) & Not(
                    In('portal_type', types_not_searched)
                )

        # perform the search using the portal catalog tool
        brains = self._ctool.evalAdvancedQuery(query, (rs,))

        return brains[:limit], norm
```